# Decisional problems vs Optimization problems : NP-COMPLETE vs NP-HARD

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

I'm studying some of computation theory and i encounter a big question mark. I have an optimization problem and i have to proof that is NP-HARD. I know that my problem can be reduced to another np-complete problem so my problem is np-hard. But my question is: why some algorithms are np-hard for the combinatorial version and the same problem transformed in a decision problem are np-complete?

I mean, if i have an optimization problem, is this np-hard because the decision problem can be reduced in a np-complete problem?

Comment: We had a discussion about this somewhere here, unfortunately I can't find it. For a problem to be NP-complete, it must be in the class NP which contains only decision problems. Optimization problems are not decision problems. They have a decision equivalent, and if it is NP-complete, then you can reduce optimization to this decision so you call it NP-hard. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Eugene Yeah, I can't quite remember what question it was, either. Small correction, though: the optimization problem is **NP**-hard because you can reduce the **NP**-complete decision problem _to_ it, not the other way around.

Answer (score 5):

NP-hardness is a category that applies to both decision problems and optimization problems. In contrast, NP-completeness is a category that applies only to decision problems.

Here are the relevant definitions:

- A decision problem is in NP if it is accepted by some polynomial time nondeterministic Turing machine.
- A decision problem is NP-hard if all problems in NP can be reduced to it in polynomial time.
- A decision problem is NP-complete if it is both in NP and NP-hard.
- An optimization problem "max $f(x)$ subject to $x \in X$" is NP-hard if the decision problem "given $x$ and $y$, does there exist $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \geq y$?" is NP-hard.
- An optimization problem "min $f(x)$ subject to $x \in X$" is NP-hard if the decision problem "given $x$ and $y$, does there exist $x \in X$ such that $f(x) \leq y$?" is NP-hard.

The decision problems used to define NP-hardness for optimization problems are known as *decision versions* of the optimization problems.

One could extend the definition of NP to optimization problems in various ways. For example, we could say that "max $f(x)$ subject to $x \in X$" is in NP if its decision version is in NP. This would also allow us to define NP-completeness for optimization problems. But for some reasons these definitions are not standard.

Let me also mention [FNP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FNP_(complexity)), an extension of NP to functions.

Comment: I suspect the answer is yes but just to clarify: Is it possible that solving the problem "given $x$ and $y$, does there exist $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\leq y$" is easy (say it is in $P$) but finding that $x$ is hard (say $NP$)? 

In general, does stating that an optimization problem is in $P$ give us any guarantees about how hard it is to find the optimizer or does it only make a statement about how easy it is to determine the existence of such an optimizer?

Comment: There is an entire complexity class, called TFNP, consisting of problems in which $x \in X$ is guaranteed to exist but is expected to be hard to find.