# How can i prove that MAX-CUT is in NP?

Tags: np, max-cut

How can i show/explain/prove that Max-Cut is in NP?
"For a graph, a maximum cut is a cut whose size is at least the size of any other cut. The problem of finding a maximum cut in a graph is known as the Max-Cut Problem."

Thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article you are citing tells you why it is easy to see that the decision version of the problem is in NP. Quote : "It is easy to see that the problem is in NP: a yes answer is easy to prove by presenting a large enough cut."

Comment: The NP version is, given a graph and an integer $k$, to determine whether the graph has a cut containing at least $k$ edges.

Comment: @Tassle - you are not helping. clearly i saw this cite in wikipedia. the question is why if i want to prove that max-cut is in NP is need to talk about the this decision problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision version of MAX-CUT is as follows:

> Given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, is there a cut in $G$ containing at least $k$ edges?

This version is clearly in NP.

Comment: What you are talking about the decision version? what is the formal way to do it?

Comment: MAX-CUT can be considered both as a decision problem (as in my answer) and as an optimization problem (given a graph, find a cut maximizing the number of edges cut). The version you quote in your OP is unfamiliar to me.

Comment: NP is a category of decision problems. Only decision problems can be in NP.

Comment: The version im talking is this one (as you wrote): "given a graph, find a cut maximizing the number of edges cut"

Comment: This is not a decision problem, so it cannot be in NP. Only decision problems can be in NP. A decision problem is one in which the answer is either Yes or No.

Comment: It is enough to say: "Let's look at the decision problem of Max-Cut, and not Max-Cut itself, ..." ???

Comment: Just like you cannot prove that your cat is in NP, so you cannot prove that the optimization version of MAX-CUT is in NP, since NP is a category of decision problems. When we say that an optimization problem is in NP, we really mean that its decision version is in NP.

Comment: See also https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/67938/decisional-problems-vs-optimization-problems-np-complete-vs-np-hard.

Comment: Ok, that is what i was missing, thanks!